# symfony2 http 403 error (access denied) for CSS file

Tags: css, symfony, twig, assetic

I have a very weird situation, **one** of my CSS files is not able to load, I see HTTP 403 error in firebug.

My twig:

```
<head>
    {% block head %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/my/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/my/js/jquery-ui.min.js</script>       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bundles/my/css/Aristo/Aristo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bundles/my/css/style.css" />
        {% endblock %}
</head>
```

My files structure:

[image]

I've run `php app/console assets:install web --symlink` successfully

`app/console assetic:dump` returns:

```
Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is on.
```

**Note:** js/jquery.min.js, js/jquery-ui.min.js and css/style.css loads fine, only Aristo/Aristo.css yells HTTP 403 error

**Edit**
GET http://my.local/bundles/my/css/Aristo/Aristo.css
Response message:

```
Response Header

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2013 18:28:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 260
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Response HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /bundles/my/css/Aristo/Aristo.css
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at my.local Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Can anyone advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `asset` instead of direct path to your ressources :

`<link href="{{ asset('css/Aristo/Aristo.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets

Hope it's helpful

Best regard

Comment: The same issue... BTW, when I check the URL in firebug, is **correct**, but I get a HTTP 403 error

Comment: Also.. does it make sense that this is happening to **only one file**?

Comment: Can you edit your message and post the 403 error message ? Thx

Comment: Edited my question with the server response

Comment: Did you check files permissions ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

Comment: Good point!! I've set my file permissions correctly but I didn't checked **Aristo** directory.. I just downloaded it.. I set 775 permission on `Resources/public/css/Aristo` and it works fine :D Thanks